# Why are unordered lists used for horizontal menus in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Why are unordered lists used for horizontal menus rather than just styling the `<a>` tags? I have this CSS, and it works perfectly:

```css
#menu {
    width: 700px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: #00604F;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu a {
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0C61B4;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu a:active, #menu a.active {
    background-color: #07396A;
}

#menu a:active, #menu a.active {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a>Hello</a>
    <a>World!</a>
</div>
```

The `<a>` tags can have whatever properties you want (such as href, onClick, etc.).

Comment: Semantics mostly. One thing especially is that if CSS fails to load, the navigation will render as a list, which makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality, you can use whatever elements you want to use. It's your site after all.

The common argument for using uls is that a menu item is an object that can contain a link. But it could contain all sorts of things. It might not have a link at all if it's a placeholder, or a header. You might also place another `ul` inside it, and use CSS to give you a drop down for it.

In my mind, a link is exactly that. A link. If it doesn't navigate you in some way, then it shouldn't be a link. If all your menu items always navigate, then by all means use the `a` tag over `ul` tags.

But you might want to think about future proofing. Sure they all link now, but what about in future. Applying styling to the links means rework later if you have to change how your menu works. Applying the styling to the `ul`s gives you greater flexibility.

Comment: Indeed +1 also in HTML5 there is the <menu> tag which replaces <ul> as the defacto container for menus as it is more semantically correct. You simply drop the <a> links directly into the <menu> which also saves several bytes per menu item from load time by excluding the need to wrap each link with <li>.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation menu is basically a list of links, so using the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements makes perfect sense.
Inside `<li>` you can have a tags.

Comment: But isn't it much more difficult to do that, since you have to override the old formatting, rather than just setting the new formatting?

Answer (score 0):

It's semantics. Navigation is an unordered list of links, therefore they should be tagged as such.

Your style and content should be separated. `HTML` is content and should only concern itself with content. `CSS` should only be concerned with style.

If your content is an unordered list you use an unordered list tag regardless of the exact implementation to achieve a certain look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main reasons are semantics and convenience.

Semantically, the `<ul>` element encapsulates a sequence of `<li>`'s, which is the meaning at the heart of a navigation menu, because within the document content skeleton (HTML) the menu is perfectly represented by a list of links.

What is more, even if you style a bunch of `<a>`'s alone you probably still need some container to enclose them, so there would be almost no difference; better to use something which is designed to represent such concept, so that its meaning (here it comes to semantics) can be more easily understood by search engine crawlers for example.

Apart from that, as it's been said in this thread, it's your site and you can style it as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Its a standard way of using menus.I mean its common.But all are styles you can do it in your own way.